# Pages wait until ajax request has finished before changing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, request

I'm creating a website in PHP, which makes use of a different site to get user data. I have setup a jQuery function in a seperate page which takes all span elements of a class get_user_full_name.

When the page loads, this function will send $.post requests with jQuery, get the name of the user back and insert this into the span.

HTML span:

```
<body onload="loadExternalData()">
<span class="get_user_full_name" data-id="xy12345">Loading username...</span>
</body>
```

jQuery function:

```
function loadExternalData(){

if($(".get_user_full_name").length != 0){
    $(".get_user_full_name").each(function(){
        $.post(path+"loadPHPRequests.php", {student_id: $(this).data("id")}, makeHandler($(this).data("id"), "full_name"));
    });
}    
}
```

The problem comes when the user wants to go to a different page. If the request is still being made, and the user clicks a link, the page won't change until all the $.post requests have been made. What I need is for any clicking on a link to stop all current $.post requests and redirect the page.
I know that one way to do this is to save each post request as a variable and then cancel each one individually on clicking a link. However, I have created this function in an external script file then included it on every page:

```
<script src="/scripts/js.js"></script>
```

Because of this, I can't see how to track the variables this way. Is there a way to cancel all requests?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post a sample because I do not see how an asynchronous request could block the navigation.